# Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function __NGTOOLS_PRIVATE_API_2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work with an Angular project and received the following errors,

```
    $ ng serve 
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.21) is greater than your local
version (7.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:215:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:55:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/Users/Chaklader/WebstormProjects/Catalog/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)
```

The `package.json` file is provided,

```
{
  "name": "kboepdevxvd.angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "tslib": "1.11.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.11",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.8.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

How do I solve the issue?

The question can be very obvious, but, this is the first time I started with the JavaScript language, so not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated package.json from `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.3"` to `"^0.12.4"`

run `npm install`

Comment: Hello, do you know where the URL path info provides in the project? I went to the `http://localhost:4200/` and see a blank page (no error though)

Comment: You can use a different port while serving the application using `--port 4201` for example. If you are using some route configuration can you please add it to your question? Thanks.

Comment: I work with this project: stackblitz.com/angular/kboepdevxvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.html

I clone it in the local repo and run from there. I would like to see the same info as they provide in the app example. I went to `http://localhost:4200/` and find nothing.

How do I see the info and from which path of the app?